# ActionScript 3.0 Function Completion Event Listener

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How can I listen for function completion?

let's say I have this **processFile** **function**, which is triggered in Class Constructor with another event listener.

```
private function processFile(e:event):void
{
//do whatever is this function suppose to do
}
```

now I want to listnen for it's completion

When I use

> processFile.addEventListener(Event.Complete,
>   anotherCoolFunction);

I get an Errorr

> Error:   1061 posssibly undefined method AddEventListener through a stati type function

Comment: There is a common case in programming questions where a person asks "How do I do *D*". The problem is they haven't given the *A*->*B*->*C*->*D*. There is *something* you are trying to do and I assure you that broadcasting to multiple objects to declare the termination of a function *isn't* what you want to do. Care to explain what you are really trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Ya... no :)

You can only listen for events on objects who implements the IEventDispatcher interface, things like Sprite or MovieClip, or EventDispatcher.

There are a couple of solution available to you though, you could simply call the next function after you call processFile. When you call a function the next line wont execute until it is done. so in the following scenario:

```
processFile();
anotherCoolFunction();
```

You can be sure that anotherCoolFunction will never execute until processFile is completed.

Hope that helps.

Tyler.

Comment: I hoped for more sophisticated way of handling this. So last line it is.

Comment: The "sophistication" is in the simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function SomeClass()
    {
        this.addEventListener("fileProcessComplete", anotherCoolFunction);

        processFile();
    }

    private function processFile():void
    {
        //do whatever is this function suppose to do
        dispatchEvent(new Event("fileProcessComplete"));
    }

    private function anotherCoolFunction(evt:Event):void
    {
        //do whatever is this function suppose to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not possible using addEventListener. Functions are not subclasses of the EventDispatcher class (the base class that provides the addEventListener method).

I'm failing to see why you would want to do something like this tho. If you have a function and you want to know when it's done executing, simply place anotherCoolFunction() directly after the call to processFile().

If processFile() is called as a callback to an event listener, simply place the call to anotherCoolFunction() in the last line of processFile().

Answer (score 1):

A function process is syncronous, so the last line of your function would indicate that it has finished. You could directly call another function, or do a dispatchEvent() (you need to extend EventDispatcher though, that's why you get an error ;)).

Comment: The problem, though, is that if you're in the last line of a function, you're still executing that function. So, the function has not really completed yet, which is what the OP asked...

Answer (score 1):

The Jeremy approach is the right one.. 
You also could do something like this if you don't want to use 'listeners'

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function SomeClass() {
        var obj = this;
        this.processFile(function(){
            obj.anotherCoolFunction(this);
        });
    }
    private function processFile(method:Function):void
    {
        //do whatever is this function suppose to do

        method.apply({some_var_name: 'hello'});
    }

    private function anotherCoolFunction(data):void
    {
        //do whatever is this function suppose to do

        trace(data.some_var_name) // => 'hello'
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never seen the use of a function in that manner. I'll have to remember that in the future -- it will probably end up being useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would listen for a dispatchEvent() that is on the last line in the function so you will need to make the class it is in extend Sprite or MovieClip. By the time the event is handled the function would have completed. If you call another function from the processFile function then it will not be finished since it's still on the call stack.